# Rest API call returning forbidden

Tags: django, ajax, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am trying to get some data by calling a rest API but it's not working and returning:

> `Forbidden: /api/networthchart/data/`

My view/API call:
(Please ignore the print functions, I was using those for testing, but I left them in here just in case)

```
class networthChart(APIView, View):  
    authentication_classes = []
    permission_classes = []
    
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        print("its working")
        labels = []
        default_items = []

        if not self.request.user.is_active:
           return HttpResponseForbidden("Not signed in") # any error you want to display    
        else:
            print("user signed in")
            
        user = self.request.user
        networth_history = user.networthTracker.objects.filter(user = user)
        
        queryset = networth_history.order_by("date")
        print("questset gotten")
        
        for query in queryset:
            default_items.append(query.networth)
            labels.append(query.date)
            print("adding")
        
        print(labels)
        print(default_items)
        
        data = {
            "labels" : labels,
            "default" : default_items,
        }
        return Response(data)
```

and the JS is:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  var endpoint = '/api/networthchart/data/'
  var defaultData = []
  var labels = []
  
  $.ajax({
    method:"GET",
    url: endpoint,
    success: function(data){
      labels = data.labels
      defaultData = data.default
      var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
      var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
          type: 'bar',
          data: {
              labels: labels,
              datasets: [{
                  label: '# of Votes',
                  data: defaultData,
                 #there was other stuff in here like bg colour and but I removed it for the sake of saving your time.
      });
    },
    error: function(errordata){
        console.log(errordata)
    }
  })
}

})
</script>
```

If you want more info on the error, it says,

> "GET /user/ HTTP/1.1" 200 11730
> its working
> Forbidden: /api/networthchart/data/
> [29/Jan/2021 20:42:39] "GET /api/networthchart/data/ HTTP/1.1" 403 13

I don't understand why it's forbidden and what should I do to make this work?

The given solution:

```
<script>
'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken
function getCookie(name) {
    let cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
        const cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (let i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            const cookie = cookies[i].trim();
            // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return cookieValue;
}
const csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');

$(document).ready(function(){ ........
```

Comment: can you please write your full URL in the endpoint variable instead of   ```var endpoint = '/api/networthchart/data/ ```

Comment: thats all I have written in the code, but, if you are wondering the complete code is http://<my  localhost number thingy>/user/api/networthchart/data/

Comment: yes try with the complete url ```var endpoint = http://<my localhost number thingy>/user/api/networthchart/data/```

Comment: I tried that, it still doesnt work, it still says, GET /api/networthchart/data/ HTTP/1.1" 403 13
its working <<--- My print statement.
Forbidden: /api/networthchart/data/
[29/Jan/2021] "GET /api/networthchart/data/ HTTP/1.1" 403 13

Answer (score 1):

The response is 403 because django requires a csrf token. In your JS file data's add

```
'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken
```

```
data: {
     'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken,
     labels: labels,
       datasets: [{
       label: '# of Votes',
       data: defaultData,
      }
```

where csrftoken is

```
function getCookie(name) {
    let cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
        const cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (let i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            const cookie = cookies[i].trim();
            // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return cookieValue;
}
const csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
```

Comment: I have posted the edited code, please check that and let me know if I am doing it right, btw, the error is not more, the data is still not coming though, but I will deal with that, I am no longer getting the error. Thank you so much for your time buddy, I really appreciate It and value it, and I promise to pass it forward :)

Comment: @Vardhan Mahajan updated my code. Also where do you get the data in your backend?